# iterating same scraper code over various urls

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Now I need to reiterate the same code on multiple sub-domains. This is my current code:

---

I've edited my code to better reflect my question:

```
for base in urls:
    urls = ["https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery","https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/almagro/empanadas-delivery","https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/palermo/empanadas-delivery","https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/villa-crespo/empanadas-delivery","https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/balvanera/empanadas-delivery",]
    page = 1
    restaurants = []

while True:
    soup = bs(requests.get(base + str(page)).text, "html.parser")
    page += 1
    sections = soup.find_all("section", attrs={"class": "restaurantData"})

    if not sections: break

    for section in sections:
        for elem in section.find_all("a", href=True, attrs={"class": "arrivalName"}):
            restaurants.append({"name": elem.text, "url": elem["href"],})
```

I need a .CSV with the following columns:

```py
[(url, name of all restaurants in each url, url for each restaurant)]
```

Comment: So you just want to iterate through a list, and for each item in the list, append it to a string which is the subdomain?

Comment: Right, I want to iterate the code above on a list of urls, and end up with three columns: subdomain - name - url

Example: 
https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/monserrat/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page= - https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-noble-galerias-pacifico-menu - El Noble Galerías Pacífico

Comment: Ok, so the the first output from you code is `{'name': 'El Noble Galerías Pacífico', 'url': 'https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-noble-galerias-pacifico-menu'}` do you want to convert that to csv format? (The output)

Comment: In a .CSV. Each sub-domain has 50-100 restaurants and I'd like a .CSV with three columns. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes. But I want it to go through a list that changes "base" in the code above with a list of urls.

Comment: So output would be: {'subdomain': https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/monserrat/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=', 'name': 'El Noble Galerías Pacífico', 'url': 'https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-noble-galerias-pacifico-menu'}

Comment: ok so you can just add for url in urls to the top of your code where urls is the list

Comment: I've changed my code to better show my question. Hope you can help!

Comment: I've posted an answer...let me know if that what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import bs4
import requests
import csv

urls = ["https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery","https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/almagro/empanadas-delivery","https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/palermo/empanadas-delivery","https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/villa-crespo/empanadas-delivery","https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/balvanera/empanadas-delivery",]

#writing

with open("output.csv", 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['subdomain', 'name', 'url']) #delete this line if you don't want the header

    for url in urls:
        base = url+ "?bt=RESTAURANT&page="
        page = 1
        restaurants = []

        while True:
            soup = bs(requests.get(base + str(page)).text, "html.parser")                
            sections = soup.find_all("section", attrs={"class": "restaurantData"})

            if not sections: break

            for section in sections:
                for elem in section.find_all("a", href=True, attrs={"class": "arrivalName"}):
                    restaurants.append({"name": elem.text, "url": elem["href"],})
                    writer.writerow([base+str(page),elem.text,elem["href"]])
            page += 1    

#reading

file = open("output.csv", 'r')    
reader = csv.reader(file)

for row in reader:
    #the output is a bunch of lists, which you can do what you want with
    print(row)
```

Here is the output:

```
subdomain,name,url
https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1,Cümen-Cümen Empanadas Palermo,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/cumen-cumen-empanadas-palermo-menu
https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1,El Maitén Empanadas - Al horno o fritas,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-maiten-empanadas-al-horno-o-fritas-menu
https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1,Cümen-Cümen Empanadas - Barrio Norte,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/cumen-cumen-empanadas-barrio-norte-menu
https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1,La Carbonera,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-carbonera-menu
https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1,Tatú Empanadas Salteñas Palermo,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/tatu-empanadas-saltenas-palermo-menu
https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1,Morita Palermo,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/morita-palermo-menu
https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1,Doña Eulogia,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/dona-eulogia-menu
...
...
...
```

Output when you read the csv with python:

```
['subdomain', 'name', 'url']
['https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1', 'Cümen-Cümen Empanadas Palermo', 'https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/cumen-cumen-empanadas-palermo-menu']
['https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1', 'El Maitén Empanadas - Al horno o fritas', 'https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-maiten-empanadas-al-horno-o-fritas-menu']
...
...
...
```

So when you read the csv, you get this (above), which is a bunch of lists that you can iterate through.

Good luck!

Comment: You are an absolute captain! Thanks heaps! Next up: scraping each individual menu. Also, how do I save this as a .csv on my pc?

Comment: Well the code saves it automatically as output.csv, but you can change the path to whatever you want in line `with open("output.csv", 'w', newline='') as csvfile:`

Comment: So when you run it, it will create a file called output.csv in the folder that you are running the program in